# Quaternion Calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, rotations, quaternions

I was reading a note on Quaternion([Link](http://becs.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/quat.pdf))  and I am happened to read a section regarding a solution of quaternion differential equation. I am putting that segment  as picture format here for more clarity than typing it here. It is all about solution of a quaternion differential equation

[image]

Here the main issue for me is, I couldnt find a solution for q(t) in time varying angular velocity. What we have here as solution is for a constant angular velocity as in  (31) and (32). **What could be the solution if the angular velocity is not a constant(it varies with time)**?. I have a feeling that equation (39) in paper [here](http://www.vsgc.odu.edu/src/Papers/Paper%20-%20G.%20Davailus.pdf) is a solution of this issue. But it is not a solid proof. It would be nice if some one suggests the proof of it or even a proper reference link for it. Material is not available that is the main issue I am facing

Comment: There's no nice formula. The best you can say in general is that the solution is a noncommutative product integral.